# retrieving bits from bytes

Tags: c, bit-shift, byte-shifting

Hey so I was wondering if someone could explain how this works, I have to retrieve the 3rd bit from  a byte, it is a bool value, and I i'm confused about how this actually works, and also if I have the syntax correct. I keep coming on so many different examples of how to do this. This is what I have:

```
                      if(apdu_parse[0] & (1<<3)){

                                 apdu_bit3 = 1;
                      }
                      else if(apdu_parse[0] & (0<<3)){

                                 apdu_bit3 = 0;
                      }                        
                    mpdu -> segmented_message = apdu_bit3;
```

what i think this does is look for the third bit of apdu_parse[0] determines if its a 1 or a 0 and stores it accordingly. as I said i keep coming across so many different examples that I think i'm starting to blend them and nothings working. the value in apdu_parse[0] is a hex value, I keep getting '93' which makes no sense.

Comment: please show us how `apdu_parse`, `apdu_bit3` and `mpdu->segmented_message` are defined (what are their types) and how exactly do you print the result?

Comment: What's this supposed to mean `(0<<3)` O_ó ?

Comment: @Pavel: Not necessary to answer his/her question.

Comment: why not just `apdu_bit3 = (apdu_parse[0] >> 3) & 1;`

Answer (score 1):

The first part is right, but the second part is wrong.

This:

```
if(apdu_parse[0] & (1<<3)){
    apdu_bit3 = 1;
}
```

means "if `apdu_parse[0] bitwise-AND:ed with 8 isn't zero", which is fine. It will be true (the`if`will be taken) if`apdu_parse[0]` has its 3rd bit set.

The other half though doesn't make any sense; nothing bitwise-ANDed with 0 is non-zero.

I would write it as:

```
mpdu->segmented_message = (apdu_parse[0] & (1 << 3)) != 0;
```

Here an explicit comparison with 0 is made, to create a `true`/`false` value, which I think is much cleaner than being implicit about it.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply write:

```
mpdu->segmented_message = (apdu_parse[0] >> 3) & 1;
```

Your code will set the correct value if the bit is set but the wrong value if the bit is not set.

```
apdu_parse[0] & (0<<3)
```

will always generate 0.

Thus

```
if (adpu_parse[0] & (0<<3))
```

will always be false since

```
Value AND 0 EQUALS 0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
mpdu->segmented_message = (apdu_parse[0] & (1<<3)) >> 3
```